Fourier transform of exponential over torus
I found the following formula for the Fourier transform on a flat 2-torus, but I don't quite know how to derive it. We have a variable $q=(q_x,q_y) \in [0,2\pi)^2$ and by considering it in polar coordinates we can also define the polar angle $\arg(q).$
The formula then claims:
$$\int_{[0,2\pi)^2} \frac{d^2q}{(2\pi)^2} e^{i(q \cdot r - m\arg(q))} = \frac{i^{|m|} |m| e^{-i m \arg(r)}}{2\pi |r|^2}.$$
Does anybody know how to derive it?

Wait, are you asking who discovered it or how to derive it?

how to derive it

$r \in \mathbb R^2$ and $m$ is an integer.

This equality cannot be true in general. Indeed, let $m$ be any fixed nonzero real number, and let $r$ be a varying nonzero vector in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $|r|\to0$. Then the modulus of the left-hand side of your equality is $\le1$, whereas the modulus of the right-hand side of your equality goes to $\infty$.

Mathematica cannot do anything with the integral in question, even in the specific case with $m=1$ and $r=(1,2)$:

So, it is highly unlikely that the integral can be expressed in elementary or special functions.

good observation. do you happen to know how to evaluate this Fourier transform?

@AntónioBorgesSantos : I have now addressed the question in your comment.

I'm curious. Does the "So" in the last line of your answer actually apply? I.e., is Mathematica that reliable that it's inability to simplify strongly indicates lack of a simple expression?

@mathworker21 : As I recall, in my experience, there have been at most two cases when Mathematica could not do an integral which was done otherwise. I also know that the Wolfram czar on Integrate has for several decades been Marichev, one of the three co-authors of the most comprehensive collection of integrals. So, I do believe that the "So" applies here. In this particular case, with the integration over a square, rather than over something like a disk, I think the "So" applies even more.
